# Flash Security Exception in URLLoader (subdomain issue)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, crossdomain.xml, urlloader

I'm working on a Flash magazine. When the magazine loads, it starts fetching all the needed images for the pages. However, I've run into a strange Security Issue :S. Let me try to explain...

This is how everything is setup on the server:

```
mydomain.com/view.html          <--- the main page that embeds /swf/theviewer.swf
mydomain.com/swf/theviewer.swf  <--- the magazine viewer

mydomain.com/img/img01.jpg      <-
mydomain.com/img/img02.jpg      <--
mydomain.com/img/img03.jpg ...  <--- all the images that the mag fetches
```

The magazine is 'hard'-coded to always fetch images from 'mydomain.com/img/*'.

If I open my browser, and navigate to 'http://mydomain.com/view.html' everything works out neat.

However, if I go to 'http://WWW.mydomain.com/view.html' instead, the viewer throws a Security Exception (an URLLoader throws it, actually).

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

UPDATE:

I've properly setup my crossdomain.xml file to allow *.mydomain.com

Also, I've set 'allowScriptAccess' to sameDomain.
Still have the same issue.

There's another thing, a couple friends that were testing the site said that when opening the site with Firefox this does NOT happen (everything's fine), however if I use Firefox, error's there. Maybe it has something to do with browser's own security policies.

Comment: change your allowScriptAccess to "always" instead fo "sameDomain". The domain matching seems to be your main issue here...

Answer (score 1):

You may have a cross domain security issue. Since the domain roots are the same, but one is excluding the "www", it is likely that the SWF (or your html/javascript) is seeing it as a different domain since it is not an exact match.

Here is an article on what I am talking about. http://blancer.com/tutorials/30030/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files/

Also, make sure that your "allowScriptAccess" property is set to "sameDomain" or "always". here is a related article on that as well.. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html

Comment: Did you put the crossdomain in the root directory? It has to be in the root directory of where your site is. Also, when I went to you page it gave me a security error #2170. This is definately a security sandbox error. But without seeing your code, it is hard to guess what is going wrong. Here is an article on security errors: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/runtimeErrors.html

Comment: Now, when I go to either link I get the same error. Try changing your crossdomain line from *.mydomain.com to: <allow-access-from domain="*" />

Comment: This will allow access to your content from any domain into the SWF. If this works, then you just need to fins the right combination of wildcards "*" to assign. Sometimes "*.*" works well.

Comment: try changing your crossdomain to:
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: I did it, didn't worked :(. It's in the root directory, www.lifelei.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: I just remembered that there is an additional line for the crossdomain that can also help. Copy paste everything after the colon and replace the entire contents of your crossdomain with it: <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain ="*" />
 </cross-domain-policy

Comment: ALSO, there is a related article that you should read about AS3's use of loader contexts: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e13.html

Comment: Did the headers thing, didn't worked :(. Read the document you gave me, tried disabling 'check PolicyFile' but I'm using URLRequest, not a Loader. Still no luck, damn :(